# Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 14 leaking clear sticky gel from lower right corner of display

Tags: lenovo-laptop, laptop-display

Our Lenovo laptop, which was manufactured on 2013/08/25, started leaking a clear gel from the lower right hand corner of the screen.  Other than being messy, it does not appear to have any effect on the performance of the device.  Any suggestion on what is causing this and if so what can be done to address the problem?  We assume that something worse will happen in due time.

Comment: Can you attach a picture?

Comment: Foto is attached

Comment: Looks like the image link didn't make it all the way here.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something like [liquid optically clear adhesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_optically_clear_adhesive) leaking from the display, perhaps due to high temperature. If this is the case, the display glass can loosen and eventually fall off.

A more serious possibility is a leak of the liquid crystal material inside the display panel itself. This can lead to failure of the entire display panel, and will typically cause black spots to appear on the screen.

In both cases, you should consider getting the system repaired. More information on common types of display problems can be found on [this HP article](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01608578) (which, for the most part, applies to laptops from any manufacturer).

Comment: OK, let me try this again.